# Django filter with manytomanyfield

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-signals

This is my models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_group_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)       
def set_group_member_type(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # change the all group members' type
```

I am trying to update `is_group_member` field with signal.

When a group is created with members, then i will filter and retrieve all the person who are group member, then i will change the `is_group_member` value to True

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you use an `is_group_member` in the first place?

Comment: I need use this field to solve a case!

Comment: I just showed here an example models but my actual model is not this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, but usually *not* by signals, since the group is *created* before the members are added. The trigger will thus be fired *before* there are members.

Furthermore it is likely *not* a good idea at all to define such field. If you later remove a member from a group, or add other members, it will be hard to update all the members accordingly. A person might still be a member of a different group. It is a form of *data duplication*, and it turns out that synchronizing data, is usually a harder problem than it looks.

It therefore is better to either add a property to your `Person` model, or annotate your `objects` queryset.

## Option 1: Add a property

We can add a property that checks if the `Person` is a member of a group. This will perform a query to the database, for each person where we query this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def is_group_member(self):
        return Group.objects.filter(members=self).exists()
```

## Option 2: Customize the `objects` manager

We can annotate the `objects` manager, such that it will run a subquery for each `Person` in the queryset. We can add this for example to the `objects` manager:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class PersonManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        from app.models import Group
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            is_group_member=Exists(Group.objects.filter(members=OuterRef('pk')))
        )
```

We can then add the manager to the `Person` class:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = PersonManager()
```